# JavaScript - print all variables / increment variable suffix to console

Tags: javascript

How can I increment a variable suffix while using console.log?

For instance - printing delta0-2

```
var delta0 = "omega"
var delta1 = "orion"
var delta2 = "kiwi"
```

I was trying to use a for loop to add a number to the end of "delta" but that doesn't seem to work? For instance this would be for a long list of items. I just want to "print all variables".

Comment: Why don't you use an object with bracket notation?

Comment: Why don't you use `Array` for delta?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: Maybe the Op inherited a legacy codebase and is trying to make some sense of the existing maze of variables. ;)

Comment: @Abhitalks You've got a point here, I've never thought about it before.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote whoever did that.. just a simple question. Tried to simplify it and not add in all of the complexities of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use eval

Like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  console.log(eval("delta" + i))
```

but eval is [**evil**](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/)

But you can create object and access it like this

```
var obj = {
  delta0: "omega",
  delta1: "orion",
  delta2: "kiwi"
};
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++)
  console.log(obj["delta" + i])
```

Comment: Its better to use an object and then do `obj["delta" + i]`

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It is all good, but it would be useful if you could explain why the Op is having a problem in the first place. Why just concatenating numbers is not working. Why do you suggest eval? What does eval do? Better alternatives can come next.

Comment: @Abhitalks Why don't you post answer instead of commenting? I think that would be better for everyone

Comment: It's ok @AnikIslamAbhi. I upvoted your answer because it was better than the other one, and just suggested an improvement. Its your choice to take it or leave it. I don't intend to add an answer just for the sake of it. Thanks.

Comment: @Abhitalks Thanks for a nice suggestion. Will follow when get time, Thanks  btw.

Answer (score 2):

You should use an array of string: `var delta = ["omega", "orion", "kiwi"];`

Then you can select each item like this:

```js
var delta = ["omega", "orion", "kiwi"];

console.log("--select an element--");
console.log(delta[0]); // print omega
console.log(delta[1]); // print orion
console.log(delta[2]); // print kiwi

console.log("--Iterate all elements--");
delta.forEach(d => {
  console.log(d); // print omega, orion, and then kiwi
});
```

Comment: Please  notice `<>` icon in editor. You can create a snippet using it

Comment: It is better to first solve the problem at hand and point out what the Op is doing wrong and why is he facing that problem. After having done that, add better alternatives to the answer. You have just pointed out an alternative, but made no attempt to actually answer the question Op asked.